# Python order multidimensional array with null values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to sort a multidimensional array based on an array within the array which is a datetime.

I have tried

```
sorted_array = sorted(array, lambda r: r[0])
```

However, I get can't compare errors.

`TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to NoneType`

The subarrays should be sorted in the same order as the datetime array.

Here is an example of the output I would be hoping for.

```
ar = [[datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 11, 4, 0, 30,tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)), datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 11, 4, 0, 29, zinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)), datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 11, 4, 0, 28, zinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None))]],[None,2,1],[None,2,1],[None,2,1]]
```

Would be ordered as

```
ar = [[datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 11, 4, 0, 28,tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)), datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 11, 4, 0, 29, zinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)), datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 11, 4, 0, 30, zinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None))]],[1,2,None],[1,2,None],[1,2,None]]
```

EDIT:

I have been able to find a solution by converting the array to a Pandas DataFrame

```
dataframe = df(ar)
sorted_data = dataframe.sort_values([0],axis=1).values
```

However, I am not sure if this is really the best approach. Also, for whatever reason 1 of my datetimes seems to be converted into a timestamp when turned into a dataframe. Not sure why. The sorting gives me exactly what I want though.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: How do you expect the entire sub list of [[1,2,3...]] to be sorted? Can you just omit that last item, as a slice?, when you sort?

Comment: Sorry, I was getting tired when I posted this. All the arrays should be ordered as the timestamps. I also noticed in my example that the timestamps were not wrapped in an array. I have updated this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order each sub-array according to the dates sub-array as follows

```
sorted_ar= [ sorted(ar[0]) , [x for _,x in sorted(zip(ar[0],ar[1]))] , 
[x for _,x in sorted(zip(ar[0],ar[2]))] ]
```

- `sorted(ar[0])` sorts the first sub-array ( the dates sub-array ) normally
- `[x for _,x in sorted(zip(ar[0],ar[1]))]` here I zip every two corresponding items from the date sub-array and one of the float data sub-arrays , then sort the zip and append the float part of the pair to a new list.
- Finally , place the ordered lists in a new array "sorted_ar